# Possible to turn off Twig debug mode for a specific template?

Tags: theming, 8

I have overridden a Twig template for an image field, which uses [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) in order to remove the surrounding Div's.

Here is my Twig template for the field (`field--media--field-image--image.twig.html`):

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.content }}
    {% if loop.length > 1 and not loop.last  %}
        {{ ', ' }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The field is output to the src tag in the Twig template for my Media Bundle (`media--image.twig.html`):

```
<div class="allstar-image-wrap">
    {% if href is not empty %}
        <a {{ href }} {{ target }}>
    {% endif %}
        <img src="{{ content.field_image }}" {{ alt }} {{ title }} />
    {% if href is not empty %}
        </a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

However, the twig debug information outputs as part of the image URL:

[image]

Is there any way to turn off twig debug for a specific template?  Or any other way around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display only the value of a field in a content-type template](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205765/display-only-the-value-of-a-field-in-a-content-type-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my use case, which was a to add a background image to a div, I needed to add spaceless, escape, and striptags as depicted here:

```
<div class="videoPoster js-videoPoster" style="background-image:url('{% spaceless %}{{ img_url|escape|striptags('<!-- -->') }}{% endspaceless %}');">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Great solution, gonna use that going forward

Comment: `striptags('<!-- -->')|trim` worked nicely for adding a field containing a video ID to a YouTube thumbnail URL with debugging turned on.

Answer (score 7):

There is also this alternative found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223488/how-to-stop-twig-debug-from-breaking-html-when-inside-tags/232139#232139) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2672656) where you can do something like this using the triple filter `|render|striptags|trim` :

```
<img src="{{ url_image }}" alt="{{ title|render|striptags|trim }}" />
```

It worked perfectly in my case (`|escape` didn't work)

Comment: This worked for me too!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution but I decided to grab the image URL from a preprocess function and pass to my Twig template for the media bundle (`media--image.twig.html`).  This circumvents the need for overriding the image field template.

**mytheme.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_media().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_media(&$variables) {
  $media = $variables['elements']['#media'];

  if($media->bundle() == 'image') {
    $image = $media->get('field_image')->getValue();

    if(isset($image[0]['target_id'])) {
      // Load the file entity object.
      $imageObject = entity_load('file', $image[0]['target_id']);
      $variables['image_url'] = $imageObject->url();
    }
  }
}
```

**media--image.twig.html**

```
{# Build the markup. #}
<div class="allstar-image-wrap">
    {% if href is not empty %}
        <a {{ href }} {{ target }}>
    {% endif %}
        <img src="{{ image_url }}" {{ alt }} {{ title }} />
    {% if href is not empty %}
        </a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the `title` var used for the `alt` attribute of an image:

`<img src="{{ url_image }}" alt="{{ title }}" />`

I finally used [the `escape` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html) like this:

`<img src="{{ url_image }}" alt="{{ title|escape }}" />`

or shorter:

`<img src="{{ url_image }}" alt="{{ title|e }}" />`

*(`url_image` is a custom var)*

Answer (score 0):

Another solution uses the [Twig Clean Debug](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_clean_debug) module:

> Provides a filter for use in twig templates to clean away twig
>   debugging output (mostly html comments describing template suggestions
>   etc).
>
> When in twig debug mode the html comments can interfere with
>   development. This filter cleans away the suggestions using regex.
>
> Usage Must be used in conjunction with the |raw filter otherwise
>   output will be double escaped, e.g.:
>
> {{ content.field_image|clean_debug|raw }}
>
> Warning: this will throw an exeption if the site is not in twig debug
>   mode.