# Twig add attribute with value in a variable

Tags: views, theming, 8

**Using Drupal 8**

I want to print out a field's content into the `src` attribute. I have the following template for my view:

```
<div class="videoWrapperHD">
     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ rows[0].content | raw }}" 
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
</div>
```

But the iframe gets filled with my own site's "*Page Not Found*" page instead of the Youtube Video because Twig prints out a whole lot of debug comments before and after printing the variable `rows[0].content`.

Is it possible to disable the debug comments for a specific field? I don't want to have to be disabling/enabling debug to make sure it works as expected. Because **it works** if I disable Twig debugging (the comments aren't printed so the URL prints out fine) but it's tiresome to be enabling/disabling to check work.

I also tried using `{{ attributes.setAttribute('src', {{ rows[0].content }} ) }}` , but no dice.

Another failed attempt was:

```
{% set iframe_src = rows[0].content %}
<div class="videoWrapperHD">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" {{ attributes.setAttribute('src', iframe_src) }}
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

My last idea was this:

```
{% set url = rows[0].content | raw %}
{% set iframe_src = 'src=' ~ url %}

<div class="videoWrapperHD">
   <iframe {{ iframe_src }} ></iframe>
</div>
```

But it prints out **src=Array**

**SOLUTION**

The answer is in [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202885/get-views-field-value-in-twig-template), I'm pasting it here in case that one gets deleted. The author of the following answer is [@4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4)

`field.content` is the rendered field. And in views that means it is no longer a render array, but the finally rendered markup. So this is very problematic to use it as a class name, not only because of twig debug.

Better use the row data, where you find the entity object with the field data from the database. Use clean_class to escape it for using it as a class name:

```
{{ row._entity.field_myfield.value|clean_class }}
```

Comment: Is the `content` property a valid URL?

Comment: The problem is, this is rendered output, which is supposed to be rendered by a browser, not put into a src attribute or a class name, like in this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202885/get-views-field-value-in-twig-template

Comment: If the `content` property is not a valid URL than this is not possible. `iframe.src` property *must* be a URL. The `iframe.srcdoc` can be content, but this is not supported in all browsers (2016.11).

Comment: Yes it's a valid URL, it's a Youtube Link to a a video.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the nested braces here are an error - inside a `{{ }}` expression, variables don't need to be enclosed again:

```
 {{ attributes.setAttribute('src', {{ rows[0].content }} ) }}
```

But for the real answer: This template isn't the culprit - the `content` is already rendered separately, passing through its own template which adds the comments.

See [Get Views field value in Twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202885/get-views-field-value-in-twig-template), where the recommended way of getting at the unrendered field value is via the `_entity` object.