# Display only the value of a field in a content-type template

Tags: theming, 8

I'm attempting to display a plain text field so that I can use it to embed youtube videos

In my template I have

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ content.field_video }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However when it renders it produces a mess

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/&#10;&#10;&lt;!-- THEME DEBUG --&gt;&#10;&lt;!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' --&gt;&#10;&lt;!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:&#10;   * field--node--field-video--beer.html.twig&#10;   * field--node--field-video.html.twig&#10;   * field--node--beer.html.twig&#10;   * field--field-video.html.twig&#10;   * field--string.html.twig&#10;   x field.html.twig&#10;--&gt;&#10;&lt;!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/field.html.twig' --&gt;&#10;&#10;            &lt;div data-quickedit-field-id=" node="" 15="" field_video="" en="" full"="">C0DPdy98e4c&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/field.html.twig' --&gt;

" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;</iframe>
```

I understand that part of it is because I'm in debug mode, but it's also wrapping it in a quick edit field div. And even if it didn't I'd rather not exit debug mode just to work on this. Is there a way to output just the value and nothing more?
Like something similar to {{ content.field_video.value }}?

If I can't disable quick edit field by field, is there a way to print a field while keeping the HTML intact? When I put the entire iframe into field it turns the html tags into text.

I tried

```
{{ content.field_video|raw }}
```

but the output still showed the html tags as text. I tried

```
{{ content.field_video.value|raw }}
```

But that did not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to print the value by using

```
{{ content.field_video[0] }}
```

Comment: Did the above worked in debug mode?

Comment: yes it did. It only printed the value, none of the surrounding debug info.

Comment: Sadly, in my use case, this just gets me a NULL. MAybe because it's D9, or a different content type

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to use

```
fields.field_name.content|striptags|trim
```

but this was inside a `views-view-field--view-name.html.twig` template... so it might be a different use case. Drupal 9. Media oembed video content type.