# How to stop twig debug from breaking HTML when inside tags?

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

Originally this was in a views field rewrite but i have since moved it to

```
views-view-fields--[view name]--[machine ID].html.twig
```

And behaviour seems to be the same:

```
 <a href="{{ fields.path.content}}" class="menu-item">{{fields.title.content}}<span data-background-image="{{ fields.field_image.content}}"></span></a>
```

This renders fine when twig debug is set to false in development.services.yml
When twig debug is turned on, the markup becomes badly broken.

I.e.

```
<span data-background-image="

    <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
    <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
    <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/mytheme/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->


    <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
    <!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_url_formatter' -->
    <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/image_url_formatter/templates/image-url-formatter.html.twig' -->
    http://mysite.local/sites/default/files/styles/menus_image/public/menus/image.png?itok=1ZnZSCkX
    <!-- END OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/image_url_formatter/templates/image-url-formatter.html.twig' -->


    <!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/mytheme/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' -->

    "></span>
```

HTML does not support `<!-- -->` inside tags, which seems to be the core issue. 
Is there a workaround to this, or it's just a limitation of Twig debug?

Comment: I've run into this issue as well. To get around it, I was using a Chrome plugin called "Drupal template helper" (which moves the debug marrkup to its own pain in Chrome) but sadly, the plugin is now broken. See this issue for more info: https://github.com/arshad/drupal-template-helper/issues/8

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can apply `|render|striptags|trim` twig filters:

```
<a href="{{ fields.path.content|render|striptags|trim }}" class="menu-item">{{ fields.title.content }}<span data-background-image="{{ fields.field_image.content|render|striptags|trim }}"></span></a>
```

> If you want to save (not delete) for example `div or img tags` you can also write:
>
> **`{{ fields.field_image.content|render|striptags('<div>, <img>')|trim }}`**

Seen here https://www.drupal.org/node/2672656#comment-11821896

Comment: This is great. Previously I was altering $variables['fields'] values to remove the twig debug output on some fields.

Comment: How can I do this when I have a field in a view?

Comment: It's such a shame that this is seemingly the best way around this. A fix for a problem in the development environment that, without yet more messing around, will end up in production too. 3 unnecessary function calls to fix a problem that doesn't even exist in that environment.

Comment: Nice hack, agree with @DanAbrey about the inevitability of something like this ending up production.  Just another one of Drupal's many warts.